# Check the pointwise and the uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Check the pointwise and the uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with

1. $\displaystyle{f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} \ \text{ for } x\in D=[-1,1]}$
2. $\displaystyle{f_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2} \ \text{ for } x\in D=\mathbb{R}}$
3. $\displaystyle{f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{x} \ \text{ for } x\in D=(0,1)}$

$$$$

I have done the following:

1. If $x=0$ then we have that \begin{equation*}f(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n\cdot 0}{1+n^2\cdot 0^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{0}{1}=0\end{equation*}
   If $x\neq 0$ then we have that
   \begin{align*}f(x)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n^2\cdot \frac{x}{n}}{n^2\left (\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2\right )}\\ & =\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{ \frac{x}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}=\frac{ 0}{0+x^2}=0\end{align*}
   So we have pointwise convergence on $[-1,1]$ to $f(x)=0$.
   The derivative is equal to $f_n'(x) =\frac{n-n^3x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}$.
   It holds that $f_n$ is decreasing on $\left [-1, -\frac{1}{n} \right )$ and $\left (\frac{1}{n}, 1\right ]$ and increasing on $\left [-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right ]$.
   So we have that $\max f_n=f_n\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}$.
   It holds that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\max f_n=\frac{1}{2}\neq 0}$.
   So we don't have uniform convergence on $[-1,1]$ to $f(x)=0$.
2. We have that \begin{equation*}f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\end{equation*}
   So we have pointwise convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ to $f(x)=|x|$.
3. We have that \begin{equation*}f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt[n]{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x^{\frac{1}{n}}=1\end{equation*}
   So we have pointwise convergence on $(0,1)$ to $f(x)=1$.

Is everything correct so far? Could you give me a hint what we could do for the uniform convergence of the sequences of functions at 2 and 3 ?

Do we consider a function $g(x)=f_n(x)-f(x)$ and check if its maximum converges to $0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is fine, except that, in the case of the third sequence, you forgot that $0$ dos not belong to $(0,1)$. On this set $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to $1$.

In the case of the second sequence, the convergence is uniform. Differentiating, you can check that $\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+x^2}-x$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$. So, its maximum is attained at $0$, where it takes the value $\frac1n$. By a similar argument, the maximum of $\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+x^2}+x$ on $(-\infty,0]$ is also $\frac1n$. So,$$\sup\left|\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+x^2}-|x|\right|=\frac1n$$and therefore the convergence is uniform

The third sequence doesn't converge uniformly to $1$, because$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\left(\frac1{n^n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0.$$

Comment: At sequence 2 : At the interval $(-\infty, 0]$ the derivative is equal to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}+1=\frac{x+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}$. How do we see the sign? We want to show that it is always positive, right? But how do we see that?

Comment: \begin{align}\frac x{\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+x^2}}+1>0&\iff1>\frac{-x}{\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+x^2}}\\&\iff1>\left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+x^2}}\right)^2\\&\iff1>\frac{x^2}{\frac1{n^2}+x^2},\end{align}which is true, since $x^2<\frac1{n^2}+x^2$.

Comment: Ahh ! see!! As for the third sequence we want to show that the supremum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ tends to $0$ but at $x=\frac{1}{n^n}$ we get $\left |f_n\left (\frac{1}{n^n}\right )-f\left (\frac{1}{n^n}\right )\right |=\left |\frac{1}{n}-1\right |\rightarrow 1\neq 0$ so also the supremum doesn't tend to $0$ and so we get that the convergence is not uniform. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: I have a question. In this case we used supremum, but in my other post we used max. If we know that the function gets this value we can use max otherwise we use sup. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Also, keep in mind that the maximum of a function, if it exists, is equal to its supremum.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!! :-)